# Google Earth Engine only clipping the boundary of polygon?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

My code is

```
var study_area = ee.FeatureCollection('users/new_external_boundary');
var study_area_ = study_area.geometry();

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD12Q1');
var igbpLandCover = dataset.select('LC_Type1')
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(study_area_)});
  
//var cliped = igbpLandCover.clip(study_area_);

var igbpLandCoverVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 17.0,
  palette: [
    '05450a', '086a10', '54a708', '78d203', '009900', 'c6b044', 'dcd159',
    'dade48', 'fbff13', 'b6ff05', '27ff87', 'c24f44', 'a5a5a5', 'ff6d4c',
    '69fff8', 'f9ffa4', '1c0dff'
  ],
};
//Map.setCenter(73.88, 32.13, 6);

Map.centerObject(study_area_);
Map.addLayer(igbpLandCover, igbpLandCoverVis, 'IGBP Land Cover');
Map.addLayer(study_area_);
```

and it is giving the result like this image

[image]

My expected result is raster covering this polygon instead of only boundary of polygon

Comment: I tried with a geometry I made up since I don't have access to `users/new_external_boundary` (doesn't seem to be a valid Id anyways), and your code works fine

Comment: Where you import your polygon, click the blue icon to copy it as code and put it with your script here so people can check with it.

Comment: Hey there! Did any of the answers provided solve your issue? If so may you accept them?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the polygon you are using there is little we can do to correct the issue. It seems your polygon is actually a shapefile, maybe try adding .geometry() to your code:

```
var study_area = ee.FeatureCollection('users/new_external_boundary').geometry();
```

If that doesn't work then you need to check where your polygon came from and if you can redraw it or download it some other way.